# CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CorDebug) fails with 0x80131701 : Failed to find a required export in the runtime

Tags: .net, debugging, unmanaged

I am trying to write an unmanaged debugger for the .NET framework, but when I try to get an instance of the core ICORDebug interface I get a runtime failure with the return value from CoCreateInstance. What am I doing wrong?

```
CComPtr<ICorDebug> debug;
HRESULT hr;    
hr=debug.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CorDebug,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
//hr=0x80131701
```

Comment: "unmanaged debugger" and ".NET framework" are contradictions. What you're trying to achieve is nigh-impossible without having deep insight int to the mechanics of _ALL_ of the .NET framework binaries and the entire CLR - in which case you would posess copyrighted knowledge about microsoft products.

Comment: Knowledge like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch59zxfc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.NET's execution engine returns error codes starting with 0x8013. The details are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yizhang/archive/2010/12/17/interpreting-hresults-returned-from-net-clr-0x8013xxxx.aspx

Your particular code has something to do with "Export not found" which probably make more sense to an unmanaged C++ coder.

I don't see why you couldn't write an unmanaged program to debug managed .NET although it sounds like extra effort. ICorDebug is a COM interface anyway so if your debugger is managed then you'll learn a lot about COM Interop. :-)

Comment: When I do this in C Sharp, I use the CoCreateInterface overload that has 5 arguments, including the interface ID. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Yes, that is how to interpret the error. But not an explanation on how to fix it or what is actually wrong in my case.

Comment: I think you're doing it the .NET 1.1 way.

Comment: Here is the managed example to get the interface the .net 4 way. Hopefully it's clear enough to convert to C. https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2010/11/24/updating-the-managed-debugging-api-for-net-v4/